# Camera folder not accessible over USB

Tags: windows-10, android

I've had my Moto X (2nd gen) for over two years, and it's been working fine. I've taken thousands of photos, and mostly I've transferred them onto my PC by plugging the USB cable in and connecting for `Transfer files (MTP)`.

But today, when I plugged in it and chose MTP, the Camera folder wasn't there. The parent folder `DCIM` is there, and also the sister folder `Facebook` is present.

I can see the photos in the Gallery app on the phone, and if I look at their details, they have the expected path (e.g. `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20161218_173719376.jpg`).

I've tried restarting the phone as well as force-stopping the camera, gallery and file manager apps, but this didn't seem to change anything.

Does anyone have any ideas what this might be caused by?

Phone details:

```
Android 6.0
System version: 24.11.18.vectara_retgb.retgball.en.GB retgb
Build number MPE24.49-18`
```

Comment: Did you try [clearing the cache of the Media Storage app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1719628)?

Comment: I didn't try that, no. Maybe would have been an alternative fix, to the one Seb posted below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried renaming `Camera` to `SomethingElse` and seeing if it shows up in the mounted view? Then rename it back just to keep the actual Camera working!

I have a friend who had this exact issue, and he found out that this fixed it for him.

Comment: Yes, that seems to have fixed it! Still curious about what might have caused it in the first place, though...